# How to hide the password in a way that it can not be read through Developer tool

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please find the attached screen shot where the password is visible if you user developer tool in chrome or firebug in firefox.

I have used below control.
   [image]

```
<asp:textbox id="txtPassword" CssClass="icon-password" TabIndex="2"  runat="server" textmode="Password"></asp:textbox>
```

I want to hide password in a way that it can be visible to developer tool or other methods.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This is the way a html password input works and I doubt there is a way to get around this. The only way would be to encrypt every keystroke but then your encryption logic would be client-side and vulnerable just the same.

Comment: Who are you hiding the password from? The person typing it?

Comment: I have implemented the Remember me functionality. My concern is if someone open the site and if that user had checked Remember Me checkbox than the password field will pre-filled and the password can be identified by the Developer tool. In this scenario that password will be available to that user. I want to restrict it to be visible in the developer tool as well to keep it secured.

Comment: If "Remember me" is your concern, I'd suggest to scrap it and let the browser handle it - that way the password should not be visible in developer tools - at least it didn't when I tried in FF.

Comment: Why is your "Remember me" function saving the password locally?? Just set a cookie!

Comment: i have set it in a cookie only. Even though if you inspect the textbox element  with developer tool, the password can be visible in the value attribute of textbox.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the OP's question is valid even if I don't fully understand the use case.  Perhaps the OP is worried about corporate users who are using an enterprise password management tool which may allow the user to sign into various applications without actually knowing the password.  In this case the developer tools may allow the employee to do something nefarious, e.g. take a password outside of the corporation and give it to a malicious party or use it from off site where auditing controls may not be in place, that sort of thing.

Unfortunately, even if you disable the view of the password in the "Inspect Element" pane, the user could still see grab it by typing some code into the console, e.g. `Console.Log(Form.txtPassword)`.

Even if you write some clever code to encrypt the password value in the textbox and store it somewhere else (e.g. in a Javascript variable), the user could still dump all the Javascript variables using the same sort of code.

Now, you could potentially [disable the Chrome console](https://davidwalsh.name/disable-console) like Facebook does.  But the user would still be able to see the password in the Network pane.  Without changing the application on the web server, there is no avoiding that-- the password has to be passed to the web site at some point.

Instead, I would recommend disabling Chrome developer tools completely, using the [DeveloperToolsDisabled](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#DeveloperToolsDisabled) policy, which can be set in the registry via a [Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753092(v=ws.11).aspx).  While you're at it, you should probably disable the installation of any sort of tool that lets you view the traffic, such as Fiddler.

Answer (score 2):

On keystroke, temporarily save each key into your database (or memory), then replace the key on the webpage. On Log In click, on your method to actually log in query that field in the database and replace the submitted value with it. This is dangerous as you have to care about everything from backspace, keystroke, etc, but it would work.

I however believe you shouldn't be worrying about this. If the person that enters it wants to see it, what's the issue? If someone else is trying to view it while the person is entering, just push them off the computer.

Comment: The major problem with this is that if someone can access the dev tools, then they can like access wherever you are storing it instead as well, so what good does that do?

Comment: @KevinWells no they can't? If you send information to a method SetPassword, sure they can also send stuff to SetPassword but there would be no external way of retrieving that data unless you specifically write it. The information would be saved onto the server, there is no way the client could access it.

Comment: Ah, you are suggesting sending each individual character to the server. I thought you meant to save it temporarily to a local database or memory on the client, and then send them to the server at the end, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

The developer tools give you access to the entire DOM and JavaScript virtual machine.

It is not possible to hide it from the dev tools. At best you can obfuscate the password.

The real question is: why would you want to hide it? It is running in a secure environment. Only the user(who is supposed to know his/her own password) should have access to it.

You should assume the user is able to change any javascript running on his/her machine.

Comment: I gave an example of how you could hide it from dev tools (or anything client side besides something like fiddler).

Comment: I start my answer before I saw yours. Got distracted on work on something else. Additionally your solution seems iffy. It will lead to horrible bugs. I think OP should rethink whether he wants to do it.

Comment: I agree, I even state it's pretty dangerous but there are probably other better ways of doing it, doesn't mean that there are none :P